# Clear all checkboxes except clicked one

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

I have 3 checkboxes that are related in a project and when one is clicked/ checked, I want to clear the others and leave the clicked checkbox checked. Basically radio button behavior. The reason I'm not using radios is per client and style purposes.

My current function works, however as I am using `forEach`, it is clearing all the checkboxes. Is there a way to keep the current clicked one checked?

```js
clearCheck(...checkboxToClear) {
  checkboxToClear.forEach(checkboxToClear => {
    if (this.formData[checkboxToClear] != "") {
      this.formData[checkboxToClear] = "";
    }
  });
}
```

Example of function call on checkbox:

```html
<el-checkbox
  v-model="formData.checkboxOne"
  name="checkboxOne"
  class="checkbox--center-align font--gray"
  :checked="true"
  @change="
    clearCheck('value1', 'value2');
  "
>
  Checkbox 1
</el-checkbox>
```

Comment: Do you consider to use the radio instead of checkbox? As radio only allow one being checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `v-model` fields have similar names (e.g., `checkbox1`, `checkbox2`, and `checkbox3`), you could use a `for`-loop to clear the fields by name that don't match a given index:

```html
<template>
  <el-checkbox v-for="i in 3"
               v-model="formData['checkbox' + i]"
               @change="onChange(i)">
    Option {{ i }}
  </el-checkbox>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      formData: {
        checkbox1: false,
        checkbox2: false,
        checkbox3: false,
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(index) {
      for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        if (i !== index) {
          this.formData['checkbox' + i] = false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/GRWXNOM?editors=1010)